# VueJS scrollBehavior() parameters causing an error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, router

I'm trying to set up my VueJS app to scroll to the top when changing the route to a different view. I've added the scrollBehavior method to the router configuration but I'm having some issues.

If I try to "npm run serve" I get an error when using scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) but if I remove the function parameters there is no issue. If I disable prettier it works as well but "firebase deploy" still fails every time.

```
   const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: "history",
      base: process.env.BASE_URL,
      routes, 
      scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }; 
      },
    });
```

Errors

"to" is defined but never used
"from" is defined but never used
"savedPosition" is defined but never used

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdQFV.png)

[Image of errors](https://photos.app.goo.gl/FwbBdTmewJvMb5ybA)

Comment: What are these errors you're getting? Please update your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an error from your eslint rules [`no-unused-vars`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars), simply remove the parameters since you are not using it.

```js
scrollBehavior () {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }; 
},
```

or if you want the parameter still present, you can disable eslint rules on that line

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }; 
},
```